# aligning jQuery mobile slider with button

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using a jQuery mobile slider and I want it to line up with the submit button underneath. It's  noticeably offset with the submit button underneath.

[image]

I think this has something to do with my hiding the `slider-input`.

```
<style type="text/css">
    input.ui-slider-input {
    display:none !important;
}

div.ui-slider {
    width: 96%;
}

</style>

<input type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" value="50" min="0" max="100" />
```

Comment: is there any other css affecting either the button or the slider? Based on your post it will be hard to troubleshoot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is an input showing slider input number. Hide this and set the slider margin again.

Check the DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/Rdfxs/4/

```
#myForm .ui-slider-input {
    display:none !important;
    width:1px !important;
    height:1px !important;
}
#myForm .ui-slider-track {
    width:100% !important;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```